# Error creating: pods is forbidden:<pod> failed quota: <namespace>: must specify limits.memory

Tags: kubernetes, limit

I created two deployments *(deployment happening with a kubenetes operator and there are other activities, like service creation, secret creation etc., also there though i feel they are not related to this error)* and expected for the pods to come up but pods dint come up.
when I checked the events I found there is below error for both the pods(i am listing one)

```
60m         Warning   FailedCreate        replicaset/sast-edge-5577bdcf6c      Error creating: pods "sas-edge-5577bdcf6c-94ps9" is forbidden: failed quota: app-xxxx-stable-biw9247u7z: must specify limits.memory
```

When I describe pod I see that the limits have been specified

```
 image: registry.xxx.xxxx.com/xxkl/xxx-xxxx:1.4
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: nsc-core
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 500Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
```

I also checked the quota for the NS

```
Name:          app-xxxx-stable-biw9247u7z
Namespace:     app-xxxx-stable-biw9247u7z
Resource       Used    Hard
--------       ----    ----
limits.memory  4072Mi  8Gi
```

I am not sure why kubernetes is not the specified resource limit. Need help.

Comment: share full deployment yaml

Comment: The limit was missing from the init container section.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Forbidden Failed quota` error comes when any of the containers in the pod does not have `limits` and `requests` in the spec and that includes init containers too. Adding `limits` and `requests` to all containers should solve the error.

Comment: Emphasis on *init containers too*. I was deeply confused why i couldn't spin up a certain pod in my namespace until i noticed that this pod also specified an init container. As suggested in similar SO questions, `LimitRange` can fix this by automatically setting requests and limits for any pod, incl. init containers as well.

Answer (score 4):

Add something like this under spec section

```
containers:
- name: nsc-core
  image: registry.xxx.xxxx.com/xxkl/xxx-xxxx:1.4
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: "2"
      memory: 2000Mi
    requests:
      cpu: "0.2"
      memory: 1500Mi
```